# How to disable GPUs in H2O AutoML

Tags: gpu, xgboost, h2o, automl, h2o.ai

When I run an experiment with H2O AutoML, I got the error: "**terminate called after throwing an instance of 'thrust::system::system_error' what():  parallel_for failed: invalid resource handle**". This error message [comes from](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/6167) XGBoost and it is because of the GPU limit exceed.

While I'm using the regular XGBoost, I set the cuda visible devices parameter to blank to disable GPUs. However, this arguments seems to be ignored in H2O AutoML - XGBoost implementation.

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = ""
```

Currently, the only xgboost [can be run](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/faq/general.html?highlight=gpu#can-we-make-use-of-gpus-with-automl) on gpu in H2O AutoML.

The question it that anybody knows how to disable GPUs in H2O AutoML?

As a workaround, I excluded XGBoost algorithm to run my experiment for now. The trouble is passed when I exclude XGBoost but I do not want to give up the power of XGBoost.

```
from h2o.automl import H2OAutoML
model = H2OAutoML(max_runtime_secs = 60*60*2, exclude_algos = ["XGBoost"])
```

Answer (score 1):

That's definitely an oversight and we will need to add the ability to turn on/off and/or specify the GPU.  I opened a [ticket](https://h2oai.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-7985) for this.  I wonder if there's a way to temporarily disable the GPU at the system level (outside of H2O/Python) in the meantime?  Thanks for the report!

Comment: Sure, gpu can be disabled in docker level but if you are using a shared server that might not be possible. As I mentioned, I exclude XGBoost and I can run AutoML if this is handled within h2o, then that would be amazing. Thank you.

Comment: We will fix this.